# Typescript does not throw an error when wrong type of prop is passed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm just trying out typescript to see what's all the fuss is about, but I'm having some problems with type checking.

I'm intentionally passing wrong props to functional component to see if an error is thrown, but its not and cant seem to find the reasson.

Button component

```
interface Props {
  label: string;
}

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={tailwind(
        "rounded-full border-2 rounded-lg py-2 px-4 bg-blue-100 border-blue-600"
      )}
    >
      <Text style={tailwind("text-xl")}>{label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Button used

```
    <View style={tailwind("w-full h-full flex justify-start")}>
      <View style={tailwind("w-full")}>
        <Button text={true} />
      </View>
    </View>
```

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You expect to see an error on compile time? Is your code compiling properly ? How do you compile ? Do you have Typescript enabled in your IDE so your IDE shows you the error when you edit the file ?

Comment: Yes, I expect to see an error on compile time, its compiling properly, I'm using react native with expo, so whatever expo does to compile, I do have typescript enabled and I'm using VSCode with TSlint, but it doesn't show me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here in the future - I figured it out. It seems that babel was catching my typescript files and compiling them into JS without type checking and other TS stuff, so I modified my CLI command to use npm package concurrently to run TS and expo in parallel.

```
"ios": "concurrently -k -n TYPESCRIPT,EXPO -c yellow,green 'yarn tsc --watch' 'expo start --ios'"
```